# React - Is there any way to ignore embedded <style> tag?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In my react project, I am getting some response from rest API as HTML document.

In some scenarios, there is some embedded styles css are coming in response which is overriding my project CSS.

Basically, I wanted to ignore that embedded styles. Any help would be appreciated.

Resolved:- Check below solution (using regex)

Comment: You can use `!important` in your project CSS to override styles brought by API or to make your project CSS less general

Comment: I know but not a fan of using !important.

Anyways, thanks for your answer @ethvlad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why not use regex and cut everything between 
`<style> CSS from response </style>`
?
then replace it for empty string " ".

Here is a regex that make do it
`const regex = /<style>((.|\s)*?)<\/style>/gim;`

[image]

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: itemsToRender.replace(regex, '') }} />`

Comment: I am getting whole html document as response not just <style>, so just example of response is like:-
```<!doctype>
      <html>
        <body>
            some html
            <style>some css</style>
         </body>
  </html>```

Comment: Regex can backfire and you may find yourself refining the expression over time as new test cases arise. For example this one won't handle attributes on the `style` tag, e.g. `<style type="text/css">`. Btw no need for `|\s` since `.*` also matches `\s`.

Comment: Thanks for response @pawel.

Later we have a plan to render that document inside iframe.

Comment: A bit better regex (with attr handling), but no warranty it will cover everything: `/<style[^>]*>(.|\W)*<\/style>/gmi`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function that removes `<style>` elements embedded in a node:

```
const removeStyle = node => [...node.querySelectorAll('style')].forEach(sheet => sheet.parentNode.removeChild(sheet));
```

Now you need to call this function on the node that contains html from your API response, presumably set using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`. To get there you need a 
`ref` to the node, and pass it to the style cleaning function when the HTML has changed.

[Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbk5c4y9/)

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._node = React.createRef();  // create the ref to assign to in render()
    this.state = {
      content: ""
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // simulate API call
    setTimeout(() =>
      this.setState({
        content: html
      }), 200);
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     // call removeStyle on the node if this.state.content has been udated
     prevState.content !== this.state.content && removeStyle(this._node.current);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <div ref = { this._node }
           dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {{ __html: this.state.content }}
    /> 
    </div>

  }
}
```